# ¿Cómo puedo unir dos tablas (T1 y T2) en SQL, que muestre de T1 todos los registros y de T2 solo los registros que tengan alguna relación con T1?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, transact-sql

Buenos días estimados colegas, espero se encuentren bien. Actualmente me encuentro realizando una consulta en SQL Server para ver el reporte de ventas mensual de un producto en específico. El detalle está en que, cando intento hacer LEFT JOIN (esto porque quiero ver todos los productos, aunque no tenga ventas registradas) los resultados son similares a INNER JOIN, o sea, solo muestra los datos que tiene relación.

**Consulta utilizada:**

```
 select ARTICULO, sum(CANTIDAD)              
 from ARTICULO LEFT JOIN VIEW_VENTAS_EXACTUS on ARTICULO = ARTCODIGO
 where PROVEEDOR = 00024                    
 AND MONTH(FECHA_FACTURA) = 2                
 AND YEAR(FECHA_FACTURA) = 2021             
 AND ACTIVO = 'S'                            
 group by ARTICULO
 order by ARTICULO
```

**Resultado:**

```
  |ARTICULO  |sum(CANTIDAD)|
  
  |00494      |4.00000000   | 
  
  |00495    |0.00000000   |
  
  |00499    |20.00000000  |
  
  |00501    |44.00000000  |
  
  |00503    |222.00000000 |
  
  |00504    |781.00000000 |
  
  |00505    |551.00000000 |
```

**Pero necesito que la consulta me arroje algo así:**

```
  |ARTICULO |sum(CANTIDAD)|
  
  |00494    |4.00000000   |
  
  |00495    |0.00000000   |
  
  |00496    |NULL         |
  
  |00499    |20.00000000  |
  
  |00500    |NULL         |
  
  |00501    |44.00000000  |
  
  |00502    |NULL         |
  
  |00503    |222.00000000 |
  
  |00504    |781.00000000 |
  
  |00505    |551.00000000 |
  
  |04915    |NULL         |
  
  |04916    |NULL         |
```

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Por favor, muestra el codigo de tu tabla SQL

Answer (score 0):

Voy a utilizar un poco mi bola de cristal, pero está fallando. Con suerte te puedo orientar de la manera correcta.

El problema es que estás usando columnas de tu segunda tabla en el `WHERE`. Al hacer eso, necesitas que los datos que estén en esa tabla no sean nulos, por lo que todas las filas que no cumplan la condición no aparecerán. Lo que tienes que hacer es que todas las condiciones que pertenezcan a la segunda tabla tendrán que estar en las condiciones del `JOIN`. Ahí es donde entra en juego la bola de cristal puesto que no sé cuales columnas pertenecen a cual tabla, pero haré mi mejor esfuerzo. Para evitar esas confusiones, siempre debes de usar prefijos en tus columnas.

```
 SELECT ARTICULO, 
        SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD              
 FROM ARTICULO A 
 LEFT JOIN VIEW_VENTAS_EXACTUS V ON A.ARTICULO = V.ARTCODIGO
                                AND V.PROVEEDOR = 00024                    
                                AND V.FECHA_FACTURA >= '20210201'
                                AND V.FECHA_FACTURA <  '20213001'
 WHERE A.ACTIVO = 'S'                            
 group by A.ARTICULO
 order by A.ARTICULO
```